# CNContactStore enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest 'Failed to update account' error

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-elcapitan, cncontactstore

I'm trying to fetch all contacts from El Capitan, and I'm using the Contacts API to do so. Here is the method where I fetch the contacts:

```
-(void)getAllContacts{
    NSError* contactError;

    //initialize the contact store
    CNContactStore* addressBook = [[CNContactStore alloc]init];

    //specify the fields I need
    NSArray * keysToFetch =@[CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, [CNContactFormatter descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle:CNContactFormatterStyleFullName]];

    //establish the request with the above keys
    CNContactFetchRequest * request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc]initWithKeysToFetch:keysToFetch];

    //fetch all the contacts   
    BOOL success = [addressBook enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request error:&contactError usingBlock:^(CNContact * __nonnull contact, BOOL * __nonnull stop){
        //I'm doing nothing here to try to isolate the problem, but even if I do something here, the problem remains
    }];

    //success is always true
    //contactError is always nil
    //5 or so seconds later, I see the error output to the console
}
```

Nothing fancy going on, but I everytime after this method executes, 5-10 seconds later the following error is output to the console:

`[Accounts] Failed to update account with identifier 72360D58-3D7H-49FC-1086-QRCIEQ8A991A0, error: Error Domain=ABAddressBookErrorDomain Code=1002 "(null)"`

I'm not explicitly trying to update any accounts. If I don't include the `enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest` call, then no error is output. I've tried this on multiple different Macs with different contact lists, and I get this same error. I am also checking that the CNContactStore authorization status is `CNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` before I invoke `getAllContacts`.

This is really frustrating, I'm starting to suspect this might be a bug in the Contacts API? Has anyone else seen this issue, or have any idea what might be causing it? Thanks for the help!

PS. I changed the ID of the account in the error statement in case that is a security concern :)

Comment: I can run this code on Mac OS 10.11.5 without problem. Personally, I would request authorization asynchronously to avoid blocking the thread, but it works as is, too. I don't think the problem rests in the code above, but rather something else in your configuration and/or project.

Comment: Thanks Rob, it's great to know that you don't get this error. I'll try with a new project. And I do actually do things asynchronously, I just left it out of my question to simplify the code :)